# Working with json using Jquery

Tags: jquery, json

I have such json :

```
[{"pk": 1, "fields": {"name": "name 1", "description": "description 1", "image": "absolute url 1"}, "pk": 2, "fields": {"name": "name 2", "description": "description 2", "image": "absolute url 2"}}]
```

and i need access to fields, e.g.

```
$.getJSON("/json/", function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(key, value) {
        $.('#id1').append([data.pk]);
        $.('#id2').append([data.fields.name]);
```

Comment: Do you mean value.pk and value.fields....

Comment: You need to give more information on what exactly you want to do and where you are having problems. Without that, no one can really help you.

Comment: The JSON is incorrect. You have duplicate `pk` and `field` properties in the same object.

Comment: Sorry, probably im incorrect ask a question.. i need just access to "fields" attributes (name, description,image) and pass it to DOM.

Comment: Guffa, those JSON returned by json.dumps (Python lib)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several errors in your code. Also your JSON is malformed.

```
var data = [{
    "pk": 1,
    "fields": {
        "name": "name 1",
        "description": "description 1",
        "image": "absolute url 1"
    },
    "pk": 2,
    "fields": {
        "name": "name 2",
        "description": "description 2",
        "image": "absolute url 2"
    }
}];
```

It has only one object with several similar properties, the last similar property overwrites the previous one, this means that the object's `pk` property for example is set to 2. It's probably supposed to have this structure (an array of 2 objects):

```
var data = [
{
    "pk": 1,
    "fields": {
        "name": "name 1",
        "description": "description 1",
        "image": "absolute url 1"
    }
}, 
{
    "pk": 2,
    "fields": {
        "name": "name 2",
        "description": "description 2",
        "image": "absolute url 2"
    }
}];
```

Now, you can read the objects' properties this way:

```
$.each(data, function (index, value) {
    console.log("pk: ", value.pk);
    console.log("fields.name: ", value.fields.name);
});
```

Also note that for creating a jQuery object you should remove the `.`:

```
$('#id1').append(value.pk);
```

Comment: Yes! I did it with your answer, Thank you much!